# Android JNI/C++/CMake: how to add and build interdependent C++ libraries?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am a newbie with JNI/CMake. I created an empty Java/C++/JNI project. Then I added 3 libs (= .h and .cpp files) in 3 different folders. Here is the structure of my project folders:

```
-cpp (with lib-native.cpp and CMakeLists.txt inside)
--lib1usedbylib3 (with .h/.cpp files inside + CMakeLists.txt)
--lib2usedbylib3 (with .h/.cpp files inside + CMakeLists.txt)
--lib3thatneedslib1and2 (with .h/.cpp files inside + CMakeLists.txt)
```

Now I need to write the code in the 3 CMakeLists files, but I don't manage to do something working... I don't want to use GLOB as it seems that is not recommended by CMake, I want to list all the files for each lib. I want to compile the 3 libs in one single lib called native-lib (built on lib-native.cpp)

I would be very grateful if anybody would be able to tell what I have to write in my 3 CMakeLists files.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Google has plenty of [NDK samples on github](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples), all/most of which use CMake. You may want to look at those, and then look up the commands you find there in the CMake documentation.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. What are the 'android' and 'log' libs mentioned in most of these examples ; for example here : https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/main/native-codec/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt And what means things like set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -UNDEBUG") or set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function") ? Thanks.

Comment: `liblog` and `libandroid` implement parts of [the native Android APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis). `set` sets a CMake variable, in these two particular cases it's used to add some C and C++ compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a CMakeLists.txt file in the top directory and include the subdirectories like that:

```
set(DIRS
    cpp
    lib1usedbylib3
    lib2usedbylib3
    lib3thatneedslib1and2
)

foreach(LIBRARY ${DIRS})
        message("==> CMake generation for ${LIBRARY}...")
        add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${LIBRARY})
endforeach()
```

And then in each directory, create a library, and finally process the build libraries in the main CMakeLists to link and mingle them as you wish.